# Uncomment some extensions in php.ini file through .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my project im using `iconv()` but I got error like

> iconv() detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string

when im using `iconv()` in my code.

I got a solution after quite a lot of searches that is to use `mb_detect_encoding()`. But i got error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding()

So that i want to uncomment these lines in php.ini. im unable to find php.ini in cpanel but i can change setting through htaccess file. Below lines i want to uncomment how can i achieve this.

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll 
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Comment: I dont want to uncomment in htaccess file i want to uncomment some extenstions in php.ini file through htaccess

Comment: I cant find php.ini file in cpanel @Niels

Comment: are you running windows or linux? in linux: `find / -name php.ini` else use the searchbox in windows to find the php.ini file

Comment: I cant find that file because its a shared host

Comment: well if you want full control I suggest learning how to use Linux Debian without GUI on a cheap VPN.

Comment: I dont have any idea about this can you please refer me a link

Comment: Create your own `php.ini` paste all those extensions uncommented and upload it in your root folder. It will be as your php.ini by default

Comment: ovh.com offers cheap vpn's starting from 3 euros a month. ovh will install debian for you. but you might want to start with debian in a virtual box. get to know it first before you do that. also. you might want to look into nginx rather than apache. way better.